# Primer on MathJax?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a Primer for MathJax somewhere in the SE network?

If there is, how about adding a link to the guide on the Ask a Question page for SE sites which have MathJax enabled?

Comment: How about this? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @rene that's a great one.  If we could get that cleaned up so it incorporated all the appropriate edits and then have a link made somewhere in the Ask a Question process, that would be great.

Comment: Really? It is already linked from the ask page when you edit a question...

Comment: Really.  First of all, it would be more useful on the composition page rather than the edit page.  Secondly on ham.se, there isn't the popup edit boxes like you get when you edit questions here.